# Can't open database file created by SQL Server in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I create database in SQL Server Management Studio. I tried open database `.mdf` file in Visual Studio but when I click "test connection", I get error message

> Unable to open the physical file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\database.mdf"
>   Operating system error 5: "5(Access denied)An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\database.mdf failed.
>   A database with the same name exists or specified file cannot be opened, or it is  located on UNC share

I of course run it administrator, but it not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to add a connection to an existing SQL Server database in Visual Studio, then you should not select the option that says `Attach a database file`. Also, make sure to input the correct `Server Name` and authentication details.

[[image: Add Connection Dialog in Visual Studio]

You can add a table in Visual Studio just by connecting to database and then right clicking on `Tables` under the database you have connected. Look at screen shot below.

[image: Create Table in Visual Studio]

Comment: I must create first table in visual studi , so i have to attach this file

Comment: No. You can just connect to the database in Visual Studio and then create the table. Just connect and then expand the connection in Server Explorer, and right click on Tables node to add a table.

Comment: @MonikaGalińska, Look at the second screen shot on how to create a table in Visual Studio. Just select `Add New Table` from the context menu you see in the screen shot.

Comment: Thank you very much , very helpful

Comment: @MonikaGalińska, You need to connect as I have explained and then create a new table in Visual Studio. This is the standard way of doing this in Visual Studio for an existing SQL Server database.

Answer (score 1):

You've created the database **on the server** - where it belongs. Just use it **on the server** - after all, SQL Server is a server-based solution!

Do **NOT** fiddle around with `.mdf` files - let SQL Server handle those. SQL Server is **NOT** a file-based database like Access, SQLite or FileMaker or any of those - it's server-based (and that's a *good thing!*).

To talk to your database, just define the necessary parameters:

```
server=your-machine-name\SQLEXPRESS;database=database-you-created;integrated security=SSPI;
```

and let SQL Server deal with all the nitty-gritty details. Just use the database as it's intended to be used - as a database under the control of the SQL Server database engine

Comment: Unfortunately this is my exercise i have to add first table by visual studio. Otherwise i have no idea how to define necessary parameters, that you quote.

Comment: @MonikaGalińska: and what's the problem?? You created the database on the server - now from Visual Studio, just **connect to the server** and create your table(s) !

Answer (score 0):

**.mdf** is stand for master database file. If we select authentication to be handled by Visual Studio itself, then .mdf file and all codes for creating and handling the authentication related tables will be auto generated by 
visual studio itself (*for example you can see this auto generated code by creating a web api by selecting individual account authentication*). Auto generated tables are as given below.

- _MigrationHistory
- AspNetRoles
- AspNetUserClaims
- AspNetUserLogins
- AspNetUserRoles
- AspNetUsers

And we can go to server explorer to see this table either by double clicking on the created .mdf file or **View > Server Explorer**. After that Server explorer will come then right click in the any table and select show table data option as the screen shot given below. [image]

Then we can see the already created table in mdf database and we can edit the table also if we want. Screen shot given below.

[image]